# I cant figure out the solution to Error: symbol .data is in a different section

Tags: assembly, arm

I am using ARM assembly to generate 100 random number from 1-6 and store them. The program should print the total amount of "runs" and the length of each run. A run being a sequence of repeated numbers. The problem I am having is that when I use the command gcc filename.s to compile it, I am getting the error "Error: symbol .data is in a different section". I have tried different things but this is confusing me and I cannot figure out the solution to this error message. I am running this on a raspberry pi 4 and using GNU to compile. Could someone try reviewing the code and explaining why this isn't working, and how I can fix it? Thank you.

```
.section .data

rolls:  .word   100         @ array of 100 rolls
newline: .asciz "\n"

.section .rodata


run_length: .asciz "Run length: %d\n"

total_runs: .asciz "Total number of runs: %d\n"



.section .text

.global main



@ Function to generate 100 random die rolls and store them in an array

@ Input:  Array of 100 integers

@ Output: None

roll_dice:

push    {lr}        @ Save link register



ldr     r3, =rolls  @ Load address of rolls array into r3

mov     r2, #100    @ Set the number of rolls to generate

roll_dice_loop:

bl      srand       @ Seed random number generator

bl      rand        @ Generate a random number between 0 and 5

add     r0, r0, #1  @ Add 1 to the random number to get a value between 1 and 6

str     r0, [r3], #4    @ Store the roll in the array and increment the array pointer

subs    r2, r2, #1  @ Decrement the roll count

bne     roll_dice_loop  @ Loop until all rolls have been generated



pop     {pc}        @ Return to the calling function



@ Function to count the number and length of runs in an array of rolls

@ Input:  Array of 100 integers

@ Output: None

count_runs:

push    {lr}        @ Save link register



ldr     r3, =rolls  @ Load address of rolls array into r3

mov     r4, #0      @ Initialize run count to 0

mov     r5, #1      @ Initialize run length to 1

count_runs_loop:

ldr     r0, [r3]    @ Load the current roll

ldr     r1, [r3, #4]    @ Load the next roll

cmp     r0, r1      @ Compare current roll to next roll

beq     increment_run   @ If they are the same, increment the run length

@ Otherwise, print the run length and reset it to 1

push    {r0, r1}    @ Save registers

mov     r0, r5      @ Move run length to r0 for printing

ldr     r1, =run_length

bl      printf

pop     {r0, r1}    @ Restore registers

mov     r5, #1      @ Reset run length to 1

add     r4, r4, #1  @ Increment the run count

increment_run:

add     r3, r3, #4  @ Increment the array pointer

add     r5, r5, #1  @ Increment the run length

cmp     r4, #99     @ Check if we have processed all the rolls

bne     count_runs_loop  @ If not, continue looping



@ Print the total number of runs

mov     r0, r4      @ Move run count to r0 for printing

ldr     r1, =total_runs

bl      printf



pop     {pc}        @ Return to the calling function



main:

@ Call roll_dice to generate the rolls

bl      roll_dice




print_roll_loop:
ldr     r0, =newline
bl      printf
ldr     r1, =rolls  @ Load address of rolls array into r1
print_roll_loop_next:
ldr     r2, [r1], #4
mov     r0, r2
bl      printf
ldr     r0, =newline
bl      printf
cmp     r1, #rolls+400
bhi     print_total_runs
b       print_roll_loop_next

print_total_runs:

@ Call count_runs to count the runs and print the results

bl      count_runs



mov     r0, #0      @ Return 0 from main

bx      lr
```

Comment: Assembles fine here. Double check that you have this exact piece of code and that you are actually using it and not some other file. Also, specify command used.

Comment: i have a filename with a .s extension. I am using the command "nano filename.s", to edit/save it, and then i do "gcc filename.s", which is when i get the error

Comment: And you do that on your pi and not on your desktop, right? (though the error would be different) What do you get for `gcc -dumpmachine` and `gcc -dumpversion` ?

Comment: arm-linux-gnueabihf and version 10

Comment: `.data` is a section name, unusual for something to be looking for it as a symbol name.  But I can reproduce it with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` version 12.2, using `arm-none-eabi-as` from GNU Binutils 2.39, on line `arm.s:146`, the `cmp     r1, #rolls+400`.  You left that out of your [mcve], giving people no clue which of over 100 lines might be a problem.

Comment: Note that `rolls:  .word   100` doesn't do what the comment says.  That's one `word` with value `100`.  You want `.space 100*4` or something.  And don't expect an absolute address to be encodeable as an immediate for `cmp`; you'll need to get that value into another register with something like `add r4, r1, 400` after loading the start address into `r1`.  (`r4` is call-preserved.)  IDK why GAS prints *that* error message; it doesn't really make sense, but I wouldn't expect it to work for labels in the same section either.

Comment: GAS is unfortunately not the best at having clear error messages; `clang -target arm` says "unsupported relocation on symbol"